# Error dialog when using Mac Automator to mount/connect SMB shares that are already mounted/connected

Tags: macos, connect, mount, automator, smb

I'm using Automator (on a Mac running OS 10.10) to mount three SMB shares on login. It works well. However, sometimes one or two of the shares can get disconnected. When I run my custom Automator application again (via an icon I placed in the dock), I get an error dialog (because some [or all] of the SMB shares I'm trying to mount are already mounted).

Dialog box image:
http://s30.postimg.org/m8rud8d1d/Screen_Shot_2014_11_05_at_10_38_04_AM.png

How do I stop this from appearing?

Also, say 2 of my 3 shares are mounted, and I'm trying to use the custom Automator application I made to mount the third and last share; it won't. So I have to manually disconnect the other 2 shares, and then run my custom Automator application, and all 3 shares will mount as intended.

Is there a way in Automator to check if a share is already mounted? And if so, skip mounting that share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same problem when I added **Get Specified Servers** followed by **Connect to Servers** Automator actions to my workflow and I assume you've been using the same pair to connect to Samba shares.

If this is the case you might want to opt for the **Run AppleScript** action with a piece of AppleScript code instead.  This code snippet works for me on OS X 10.10.3:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Finder"
    try
      mount volume "smb://Guest:@<hostname>/<share>/"
      delay 1
    end try
  end tell
  return input
end run
```

This action shouldn't cause any issues with the existing workflows as it seamlessly passes its input to the output in its current form.

If you need a more robust solution, e.g. check if network shares are actually available prior to attempting to connect to them, you might want to refer to [this answer on Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/3317) and an extended and more defensive version of the code above that's been provided by Jason.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chris-kobrzak  
Based off your suggestion, I made an Automator application that runs the "Run AppleScript" action 7 times (as I have 7 different servers I am connecting to.)  
For those curious, this is the modified Applescript I'm using:  
`on run
 tell application "Finder"
  try
   mount volume "smb://IP_ADDRESS/share-name/"
   delay 1
  end try
 end tell
end run`